# Any HTTPs mirrors for ubuntu repos

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-updates

Is there any reputable mirrors for `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` that allow HTTPS? I want encryption for my updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Official list of Ubuntu mirrors: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors many with https, just pick one near you.